# Browser back button only works on Chrome (not IE 11 or Safari or Firefox)

Tags: angular

The behavior can be replicated using Angular's route plunker accessed from the ROUTING & NAVIGATION doc page
 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

(1) Click on Heroes;
(2) Select a hero to view detail;
(3) Click browser back button to Heroes => Content for Heroes route is not fully loaded, dynamic content not rendered

I had the same issue running the same code locally.

```
// main entry point
import { bootstrap }            from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));

//app.routes.ts
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

import { CrisisCenterRoutes } from './crisis-center/crisis-center.routes';
import { HeroesRoutes }       from './heroes/heroes.routes';

import { LoginRoutes,
         AUTH_PROVIDERS }     from './login.routes';

import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './interfaces';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  ...HeroesRoutes,
  ...LoginRoutes,
  ...CrisisCenterRoutes
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  AUTH_PROVIDERS,
  CanDeactivateGuard
];

//heroes/heroes.routes.ts
import { RouterConfig }          from '@angular/router';
import { HeroListComponent }     from './hero-list.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }   from './hero-detail.component';

export const HeroesRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'heroes',  component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
```

Comment: You are required to supply a minimal example of the problem code here.

Answer (score 0):

Read the "Appendix: LocationStrategy and browser URL styles" at the bottom of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html.

Instead of default strategy you could use HashLocationStrategy, you won't get the nice urls, instead you will get hash links like default in angular 1 ui-router for example. But more browsers will support it better generally.

`#/dashboard` instead of `/dashboard`

You set it up like this below in main entry point, e.g. main.ts:

```
// main entry point
import { bootstrap }            from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// Add these symbols to override the `LocationStrategy`
import { LocationStrategy,
         HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } // .../#/crisis-center/
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score -3):

I ended up reloading the page when the back button is clicked

```
 // this occurs when the user clicks the back button
 window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    document.location.reload();
  };
```